# Convert space separated string of coordinates into JavaScript object array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation, location

This space separated string:

```
const polygon = "42.44492,75.637764 42.445503,75.64534 42.433681,75.6604"
```

..should be converted to array consisting objects:

```
const polygon = [
    { lat: 42.44492, lng: 75.637764 },
    { lat: 42.445503, lng: 75.64534 },
    { lat: 42.433681, lng: 75.6604 }
]
```

What is the most simplest (beautiful) way to achieve this with JavaScript? Is there a nice one liner for this? The initial string can consist any amount coordinate pairs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use split to get every row and then map every row to split by comma:

```js
const polygon = "42.44492,75.637764 42.445503,75.64534 42.433681,75.6604";
const formated = polygon.split(' ').map((item) => {
  const [ lat, lng ] = item.split(',');
  return { lat, lng };
});
console.log(formated);
```

If you wish to parse the values you should use let instead:

```js
const polygon = "42.44492,75.637764 42.445503,75.64534 42.433681,75.6604";
const formated = polygon.split(' ').map((item) => {
  let [ lat, lng ] = item.split(',');
  lat = parseFloat(lat); // or any other transformation you wish to make
  lng = parseFloat(lng);
  return { lat, lng };
});
console.log(formated);
```

Comment: Great! Any idea how to store object values as doubles instead of strings? I tried to use parseFloat but got errors.

Comment: Actually I did parseFloat in wrong place. I'm not sure where should I use it in the example above.

Comment: I'm adding my previous comment to the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

use map function along with split function

```js
const polygon = "42.44492,75.637764 42.445503,75.64534 42.433681,75.6604";

const res = polygon.split(' ').map(s => {
  const [lat, lng] = s.split(',');
  return { lat: Number(lat), lng: Number(lng) };
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const polygon = "42.44492,75.637764 42.445503,75.64534 42.433681,75.6604"
const polygonsArr = polygon.split(' ')
const result = []
polygonsArr.map(item => {
    let a = item.split(',');
    result.push({"lat": a[0], "lng": a[1]})
})
console.log(result)
```